# cannot make a text view scroll - xcode 4.3

Tags: ios, xcode, uiscrollview, scroll, uitextview

I am using Xcode 4.3

I have a single screen that has a text view `UITextView` that I wish to be able to scroll just vertically.

I have added a scroll to the screen `UIScrollview` and a `UITextview` on top of that.
I have created a new outlet called  theScroller and in the `viewcontroller.m` file added the line.

```
(void)viewdidLoad 
{
self.thescroller.contentSize=CGSizeMake(280.0,600.0);
```

However in most tutorials I have watched, they all add a line before this to set scroller to YES, but in Xcode 4.3 it wont let me. How do I turn the scroller on. what am I doing wrong.?

I am a newbie at this so please keep things simple. thanks

Comment: Just be sure that what you want to scroll. You want to scroll whole textview or text inside the textview?
Try this if you want to scroll whole textview.
self.thescroller.scrollingEnabled = YES;

Answer (score 4):

Firstly, is the content of the `UITextView` larger than the view dimensions for the UITextView? If it is larger, then it will scroll, if not, then it won't scroll.

And with the `UITextView` you don't need an additional `UIScrollView` for it to scroll.

You've added the `contentSize` code, however, the UITextView won't scroll if your text isn't larger than the normal view size. `UITextView`'s automatically allow scroll if any text overflows from the size. Try adding a lot more text than will view, and see if it scrolls then.

Comment: +1 For a simple and correct answer, this is one of those things that is actually as simple as it should be.

Comment: Ok. I have removed the IUscrollview and re- added the IUtextview. Below are myviewcontroller. m and .h files. It still wont scroll. Am I missing something.

Comment: It still wont scroll. Am I missing something.                                            viewcontroller.h 
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
interface ViewController : UIViewController
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextView *Textscroller;
end
viewcontroller.m #import "ViewController.h"
interface ViewController ()
end
implementation ViewController
synthesize Textscroller;
- (void)viewDidLoad{
self.Textscroller.scrollEnabled = YES;
self.Textscroller.showsVerticalScrollIndicator =YES;
self.Textscroller.contentSize=CGSizeMake(280.0, 600.0);
[super viewDidLoad];

Comment: Thank you. it will now scroll if i use  the up and down arrows on the keyboard. Hoever still cannot see the vertical slider indicator on the  on the simulator despite adding the command. This is soooo frustrating

Comment: Having a blonde female moment - all sorted. Thank you for your patience

Answer (score 0):

I have exactly what you need in my public repo [TextScroller](https://github.com/freesuraj/TextScroller). It supports normal right to left, left to right (Like LED) or floating type that floats like the music name in music player !